# How can I render a d3 chart, export it as an image, then load the next data set, plot the next chart and export again

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, d3.js, svg

I'm building a medical application where I have to show injuries to certain people from a certain department. I'm using d3 to mark the injured areas on an svg illustration that I traced. So for example, if someone had a spill on their arm, the svg graphic would show the arm in red. I managed to do this part and write a function to export the svg as an image and show it on the same screen in a div, as a thumbnail.

My goal is to enable the user to select a department and I need to render an svg map for everyone in that department and show the thumbnails inside a div tag so they can visually see whats going on.

My data set is in this format: x1,x2,x3...|y1,y2,y3...|... where x are the ids of the svg to light up red for person X and y are the ids for another person Y.

Example:     boneID_043,boneID_046,boneID_038,boneID_029,boneID_027|boneID_043,boneID_046,boneID_038,boneID_029,boneID_027

The way I designed it is:

1. Load the data set from a SQL query
2. Load the first data group into the SVG using d3
3. Render the SVG inside a div tag #diagram which is set to display:none;
4. Run the export function to make an image blob and show it in a new div
5. Load next data group from data set and repeat

This is what it looks like after running for one person and clicking on my export to image button, which calls a function exportD3();

[image: injury map]

EDIT: Apologies, i forgot to output wthe current result. Here is what I see after my code runs, for 2 people's data groups. There is a link to a blob file, so the export did create an image blob If i click on my manual export button then it exports the 2nd person's data correctly as shown above.

[image: [blank map]

My problem is that after postback (via a button that does the query in c#/asp.net to get the data and post it inside a div) I try to loop through the data set above and load the SVG with these ids, and then run my export function but I only see blank images, as if the export ran before the svg was loaded. However after postback if I click on my export button, it does export the latest svg with the last data (y in this case).

I cant figure out why the export wont work through code. Is there a way for javascript to wait for the render to complete and then export for example could this be a concurrency issue? I thought it was because the #diagram div (where the render happens) was hidden but it does work when I push my manual button. I also did try to copy and paste the export code from exportD3() right into the for loop but that doesnt work either

Here is my code:

Assume:

1. A div tag called #diagram that hold the svg during every render
2. combined.json is my svg illustration file for the human body
3. imgSVG is a div tag that will hold multiple divs with a thumbnail image blob everytime we append a new image to it
4. bArray contains the bones affected and fArray contains the flesh/surface injuries and they will always have the same length

   ```
   var bArray = document.getElementById("     <%=boneIds.ClientID%>").innerHTML.split('|');
   var fArray = document.getElementById("<%=bodyPartsIds.ClientID%>").innerHTML.split('|');

   var width = 720, height = 720;

   svg = d3.select("#diagram").append("svg")
   .attr("width", width)
   .attr("height", height)
   .call(d3.behavior.zoom()
   .on("zoom", redraw))
   .append("g")
   .attr("transform", "translate(5.1261,2)scale(0.4152752)"); //15.1261,-38.639
   ```

Now I want to loop through the data groups within the dataset, load up the svg and export into a thumbnail and append each inside the #imgSVG div

```
for(var i = 0; i < bArray.Length; i++) 
    {
//Split the data by comma
d3.json("data/combined.json", function (data) {
            svg.selectAll("polygon")
                .data(data.Polygons)
                .enter().append("polygon")
                .attr("points", function (d) { //logic here }
                .attr("fill", function (d) { //logic here };

    //Then export to image blob
    exportD3();
}

 function exportD3()
    {
        //This function xports the d3 figures to a div tag
        var doctype = '<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>'
            + '<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">';

        // serialize the SVG to a string.
        var source = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(d3.select('svg').node());

        // create a file blob
        var blob = new Blob([doctype + source], { type: 'image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8' });

        var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

        //Next line just shows the parts affected
        var info2 = "<h3>" + document.getElementById("<%=nameInfo.ClientID%>").innerText + "</h3><br/><b>Bones Affected:</b><br />" + boneParts.join(", ") + "<br/><br/><b>Surface Parts Affected:</b><br />" + bParts.join(", ");


        var img = d3.select('#imgSVG').append("div")
            .attr('class', 'divs')
            .style("opacity", 1)
            .style('width', '300px')
            .style('height', '400px')
            .style('float', 'left')
        .html(info)
            .append('img')
             .attr('width', 300)
             .attr('height', 300)
             .node();

        img.src = url;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out for anyone having the same situation.

It seems that having the d3.json block of code inside the for loop will not work, as it will wait for the loop to finish and some weird things happen.

Instead I added the for loop inside the d3 block and looped through my variables that way.

```
d3.json("data/combined.json", function (data) {

        for(var i = 0; i < max; i++)
        {
```